# Not getting a half pyramid instead just getting a straight line of values in java

Tags: java

Hi I am new to Java and just trying out some basic programming, I just wanted to try a program where `*` prints in half pyramid but I end up getting in straight line. Can anybody please help me out?

```
public class Aestrixpyramid {
    public static void print(int n) {
        
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.println("* ");
            }
            System.out.println(); 
        }
    }
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int n = 5;
        print(n);
    }
}
```

and got output like this

```
* 

* 
* 

* 
* 
* 

* 
* 
* 
* 

* 
* 
* 
* 
*
```

instead of

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `System.out.println(String)` always prints a string ended with a new line character. Use `System.out.print(String)` instead if you want to print a few things in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to change `System.out.println("* ")` for `System.out.print("* ")`

`println` prints the text and add a line break, if you want to append characters to the same line you can use `print`